# Getting records from two tables using Intersect

Tags: sql, intersect

I want to get List of students from a particular section and with other search criteria. I am doing this:-

```
declare @sectionId int, @name varchar
select @sectionId=23
select @name='a'

select UserId, FirstName from StudentMaster
Where FirstName Like @name and UserId IN
(
  select UserId from StudentMaster
  Intersect
  select StudentId from StudentInSections where SectionId=@sectionId
)
```

but it is not giving right answer. If I only write Userid condition it works properly but I have to get list with whole search criteria.
is there anybody to help me?

Comment: `intersect` seems absolutely superfluous here. This should work just the same: `... and UserId IN (select StudentId from StudentInSections where SectionId=@sectionId)`. So your problem seems to have nothing to do with `intersect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the LIKE operand. If `@name` is `'a'` this will only return students whose name is `'a'` or `'A'`. If you want student names starting with "a" you must add a wildcard "%"

```
FirstName LIKE 'a%'
```

(Some SQL dialects like MS Access use the wildcard "*" instead of "%".)

Note on case sensitive/insensitive search. Depending on the SQL dialect and the collation used for the column the search will be case sensitive or not. If you do not want to make a case sensitive search (i.e. you want to find students whose name starts with "a" or "A"), you can do this:

```
UPPER(FirstName) LIKE 'A%'
```

Or on the SQL-Server

```
FirstName COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%a'
```

Where CI means case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sm.UserId, sm.FirstName from StudentMaster sm
    inner join StudentInSections ss on ss.StudentId = sm.UserId
Where sm.FirstName Like @name
    and ss.SectionId = @sectionId
```

Something like that should work. You just need to learn how to use inner joins.